# How to speed angular 2 website

Tags: angular

Right now I'm working on angular 2 website I have finished one module and upload this on demo path. I have test on google speed test it gave speed only 37 on system and in mobile it gives 32, Can someone guide me how to speed the website which build in angular 2. (I'm using angular CLi)

Comment: are you using prod and aot?

Comment: try using `ng build --aot --prod`

Comment: You can use g-Zip to compress data like json, css and javascript file.

Comment: Are you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` everywhere?

Comment: Thanks for replay sry for delayed replied @PardeepJain i used that but i m using fullpage componet it gives error

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "enableProdMode()" to enable the production mode.

Comment: this should be comment not answer.